# How can I separate quadrants of my dataframe by zeros

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider my dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((4, 4), dtype=int), list('ABDE'), list('VWYZ'))

df

   V  W  Y  Z
A  1  1  1  1
B  1  1  1  1
D  1  1  1  1
E  1  1  1  1
```

How can I separate the quadrants of my dataframe with zeros

```
   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  1  1  0  1  1
B  1  1  0  1  1
C  0  0  0  0  0
D  1  1  0  1  1
E  1  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: So, no. of cols and rows are always even numbers?

Comment: How did I know **you** were going to ask that?  Yes!  But my solution doesn't require it.

Comment: You know great minds.. and whatever they say about those ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new index and columns values and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
a = int(len(df.columns) / 2)
cols =np.concatenate([df.columns[:a], ['X'], df.columns[a:]])
b = int(len(df.index) / 2)
idx =np.concatenate([df.index[:b], ['C'], df.index[b:]])

df = df.reindex(index=idx, columns=cols, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  1  1  0  1  1
B  1  1  0  1  1
C  0  0  0  0  0
D  1  1  0  1  1
E  1  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: That's it!  My derivative of this `f = lambda x, i: list(x[:len(x)//2]) + [i] + list(x[len(x)//2:]); df.reindex(f(df.index, 'C'), f(df.columns, 'X'), fill_value=0)`

Comment: Why not use `insert` instead of `f`?

Comment: I was just going to say that @JohnGalt your use of insert on the indices is better.

Answer (score 4):

One ugly way would be

```
In [860]: df.insert(df.shape[1]/2, 'X', 0)

In [861]: df.reindex(df.index.insert(df.shape[0]/2, 'C'), fill_value=0)
Out[861]:
   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  1  1  0  1  1
B  1  1  0  1  1
C  0  0  0  0  0
D  1  1  0  1  1
E  1  1  0  1  1
```

**And**, another inspired from Divarkar's

```
In [897]: df.reindex(index=df.index.insert(df.shape[0]/2, 'C'),
                     columns=df.columns.insert(df.shape[1]/2, 'X'), fill_value=0)
Out[897]:
   V  W  X  Y  Z
A  1  1  0  1  1
B  1  1  0  1  1
C  0  0  0  0  0
D  1  1  0  1  1
E  1  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: This is philosophically the same thing i had in mind.  I used the `fill_value=0` argument when reindexing.

Comment: About sorting... yes, exactly.

Comment: Agreed!  Accepting @jezrael as I saw `reindex` both index and columns first.

Answer (score 3):

```
df['X'] = 0
df.loc['C'] = [0]*len(df.columns)
df = df.sort_index()
df = df[[sorted(df.columns)]]
```

If I can't sort the labels, then:

```
df['X'] = 0
col = list(df.columns)
col.insert(len(col)/2,'X')
df = df[col[:-1]]
df.loc['C'] = 0
rows = list(df.index)
rows.insert(len(df)/2,'C')
df.reindex(rows[:-1])
```

Comment: Self explanatory but you're abusing the structure of the sample data here, I don't think this deserves the number of votes it has.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is correct.  Labels could have been completely different.

Comment: Edited with another method but not that elegant

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with arrays creating a grid of places to be inserted in with `np.ix_` -

```
a = df.values
m,n = a.shape
mask_row = np.r_[:m//2+1,m//2-1:-1:-1] < m//2
mask_col = np.r_[:n//2+1,n//2-1:-1:-1] < n//2

out = np.zeros((m+1,n+1), dtype=a.dtype)
out[np.ix_(mask_row, mask_col)] = a
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out)
df_out.columns = np.insert(df.columns, n//2, 'New')
df_out.index = np.insert(df.index, m//2, 'New')
```

Sample output -

```
In [375]: df_out
Out[375]: 
     V  W  New  Y  Z
A    1  1    0  1  1
B    1  1    0  1  1
New  0  0    0  0  0
D    1  1    0  1  1
E    1  1    0  1  1
```

Comment: Do you suggest mask is better than `out = np.zeros((m+1,n+1), dtype=a.dtype); out[m//2] = 1; out[:, m//2] = 1`?

Comment: @JohnGalt Won't you need need four such slicing-assignment steps there?

Comment: Why four, two would just do. Those three lines are enough to generate final out array with cross.

Comment: @JohnGalt So, that gives us `out` as the final array output (inverted tho), but assuming the original dataframe had all 1s?

Comment: Hmm, I get it now, atleast here OP has all ones.